# Show html page(from different file) inside a leafleat marker

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers, html-popup

I am developing a web application and I would like to be able to show a full web page inside an L.marker popup window with fixed size... Until now I figured out how to run some php or html in the popup.
code:

```
var k= new L.marker( [markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
    .bindPopup( '<a href="' + markers[0].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[0].name + '</a>' )
    .addTo( map );
    k.setPopupContent('<?php $user=$userRow['username']; echo $user; ?>');
```

This one obviously shows the username in the popup window. The thing is, that if would like to write my html or php in a separate file and include it with php, or even write my code straight inside the setPopupContent function, I would have to write all of my code in a straight line. So is there any other thoughts on how to do this so that I wont have to write my pages in a single line?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for now by simply putting a '\' char at the end of each line inside my other php or html files